# How can I open a System 9 FileMaker document in OS X 10.9?

Tags: database

I need to print some FileMaker pages that I created in System 9 (MacOS 9). Is there any free OS X 10.9 software that will open those files?

Comment: `cat` should be able to open your files. ;)

Comment: Can you not open the files from System (MacOS) 9, in the current version of FileMaker of OS X? When you try, what errors do you receive? You should be able to import them into FileMaker for OS X, as there is backwards compatibility.

Comment: @CousinCocaine, `cat` will be of little use in this case and only output worthless gibberish.

Comment: @user3439894 True, but it reads the file as was requested. Anyway my comment was useless. Just as this comment.

Comment: @sushil rao, If you do not have Mac OS 9 and and v6 of FileMaker or earlier you can download the free 30 day trial of File Maker Pro 11 and convert the file from e.g. .fp5 to .fp7 and then print the pages.  You can the delete the 30 day trial. [FileMaker Pro 11 Trial for Mac](http://fmdl.filemaker.com/TBUB/eleven/fmp_trial_fm_11.0.4.401b.dmg)  BTW FMP 11 is not officially supported under OS X 10.9 however it will probably work for this purpose.

Comment: What is your current version of FileMaker? What other versions of FileMaker do you have access to? Are you trying to extract the data, or print reports?  More information would be helpful in providing answers. Hope we can help further.

Comment: @CousinCocaine, _"but it reads the file as was requested"_ is a unless technicality in the context of being able to print and open the filemaker file.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of FIleMaker created the file that you wish to open?

Presumably, you are talking about a file created by FileMaker 5 or prior, which was the last version *not* to support OS X, which was introduced in FileMaker 5.5 (April 2001). MacOS 9 support was dropped in FileMaker 7 (March 2004). Source [Wikipedia: FileMaker Version History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileMaker#Version_history).

Regardless, the current versions of FileMaker (v14 was released just this month) only offer backwards compatibility with files created with earlier recent versions of FileMaker (v13 and v12). v11 and earlier need to be [converted to the latest file format](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10571/) in order for them to be opened with FileMaker Pro 14. Thanks to [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for that information.

However, I guess that you are looking for a *free* database application that offers compatibility with FileMaker. I would have suggested [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/) or [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/). However as [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) has commented below, you *can not* by default, open FileMaker files with these two applications, unfortunately.

Comment: FileMaker Pro 14 only works directly with FileMaker 14, 13, and 12 files. FileMaker Pro 11 and earlier must be converted to the latest file format to be opened with FileMaker Pro 14. [Learn more](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10571/) about converting your pre-12 FileMaker solutions.  Also OpenOffice and LibreOffice, by default cannot open FileMaker databases.

Comment: @user3439894 - Thanks for that correction. :-) I have updated my answer.